# Barcode Scanner dispose Exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows-ce, barcode, image

I'm having a problem with BarcodeScannerFacade in Windows CE. 
I have an app, in which the customer can create a 'case', that contains data and pictures.
I'm trying to update it, by giving the customer the ability to scan barcode with a barcode scanner.

Now, the first case ends fine, no problems, but when I start my second case, I just can't take pictures anymore, because it throws an exception with an "Unknown error". (It happens right after the CameraCaptureDialog.ShowDialog() method is invoked)

After some reasearch I found out that I have to dispose the barcodeScanner, because it somehow interferes with the CCD.

This is how I instantiate the BarcodeScanner:

```
barcodeScanner = BarcodeScannerFacade.GetBarcodeScanner();
barcodeScanner.BarcodeScan += new BarcodeScanner.BarcodeScanEventHandler(barcodeScanner_BarcodeScan);
```

So given the above research, I put the following lines in my code:

```
if (barcodeScanner != null) 
{
     barcodeScanner.Dispose();
}
```

The only problem is that it dies with a NullReferenceException when it's called.
The debugger has the following message:
"No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed."
"NullReferenceException was unhandled"
The stack trace is the following:

```
- MyLibrary.SymbolBarcodeScanner.symbolReader_ReadNotify()
at TASK.Invoke()
- System.Windows.Forms.Control._InvokeAll()
- System.Windows.Forms.Control.WnProc()
- System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
- Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()
- System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
- MyProgram.Program.Main()
```

Once I remove the barcodeScanner.Dispose() line it doesn't die with the exception, but then again, I can't take pictures anymore.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Rockbag

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement a Terminate() method:

```
public override void Terminate()
{
    // If you have a scanner
    if(barcodeScanner  != null) 
    {
        barcodeScanner.ScanDeinit();

        // Any other necessary code for cleaning up...

        // Free it up
        barcodeScanner.Dispose();

        // Indicate that you no longer have a scanner
        barcodeScanner = null;
    }
}
```

This might be of further help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446489.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should add a try catch block around your Dispose methode, you can't do something to change the external code which throws an exception:

```
if (barcodeScanner != null) 
{
    try { //try to run the dispose method on the barcodescanner to free external resources
        barcodeScanner.Dispose();
    } catch(Exception ex) { 
        //Do some logging if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: It was my first thought too, I did try to encapsule it in a try-catch block, but the same error occurs. :(

Comment: The try catch block only intends to keep your application running, by supressing the error. Not to fix the error in barcodescanner code, which is external and you do not have under control. You are just trying to dispose as much as the barcodescanner can dispose before it crashes.

Comment: anyone still has the active link to the BarcodeScannarFacade MSDN article?  I used it few years ago but it looks MS removed it but it was very good.  Anyone still has a reference to it and would share?